# Rundeck - problem with jaas LDAPS configuration

Tags: rundeck

> **[SOLVED - answer in comments]**

I've followed how-to from https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#communicating-over-secure-ldap-ldaps

Authentication works great for LDAP, but when I change to LDAPS (I am only changing *providerUrl="ldap://"* to *ldaps://* stanza in custom jaas conf), error is being returned:

```
ERROR jaas.JettyCachingLdapLogModule - Naming error
javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: <AD IP>
```

AD is listening on port 636.
I suspect problem can be with *authenticationMethod="simple"* - but when I am trying to change it to "tls:simple" (per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54912/ldapsecure-75.html) Rundeck claims there's syntax issue.

Do you had similar problem?
How switch from simple auth to tls?

Comment: Make sure that Rundeck trust on SSL LDAP certificate, add the cert to java cacert (take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42092856/10426011) or rundeck truststore (referenced at launch like this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/6268#issuecomment-664425060).

Comment: Thank you MegaDrive68k - you're helpful as always!!
I've re-added (deleted previous first) AD cert into trustore file, but still can see error "simple bind failed: <AD IP>", although this time I noticed new info in log:

Certificate for <AD IP> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [AD FQDN]
#
Ps. I am using CentOS 7.9 with java-11-openjdk-11.0.9.11

Comment: ++
1. <AD FQDN> is resolvable on Rundeck server
2. I looked into AD cert details and I can see: X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: othername:unsupported, DNS:<AD FQDN>
3. There is no possibility for me to change AD cert. 
4. Can we somehow ignore SSL verification?

Comment: Ok, I spot that AD hostname in DNS is lowercase and in cert/pem imported via openssl s_client command is uppercase.
Tried to add uppercase AD hostname in /etc/hosts but without joy.
Searching for solution which will help me to ignore SSLHandshakeException errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66116731/java-sslhandshakeexception-certificate-for-ip-doesnt-match-any-of-the-subje

Comment: ^^^ Answer in post linked above ^^^