# SSLHandshakeException certificate for <IP> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names <FQDN>

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to switch application authentication from LDAP (which works fine) to LDAPS via JAAS. The application runs on JVM. I followed vendor how-to ([Rundeck - problem with jaas LDAPS configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66025291/rundeck-problem-with-jaas-ldaps-configuration)), but I am facing a problem.

From log:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <ActiveDirectoryIP> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: <ActiveDirectoryFQDN>
```

I noticed that ActiveDirectoryFQDN in DNS is **lowercase** but in cert/pem imported from openssl s_client command is **uppercase**.
SSL certs *should not* be case sensitive, but maybe Java treats it other way around?
As a workaround I tried to add uppercase entry for ActiveDirectoryFQDN in /etc/hosts, and modifying /etc/nsswitch to:

```
hosts: files [success=return] dns
```

but without joy. I cannot modify DNS.

Is there a argument to ignore SSLHandshakeException errors and/or generally disable SSL validation for JVM (trough OPTS)?

Comment: Most probably, you have to check the existing options for your specific JVM implementation and version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why I didn't thought about it earlier - solution is quite easy: simply replaced in application configuration `<ActiveDirectoryIP>` with `<ActiveDirectoryFQDN>` as AD cert has been issued only for AD FQDN (no alt's for IPs).